# How can I break up my Matlab code into functions without creating many files?

Tags: matlab, function

I tried coding up a function in a Matlab .m file:

```
function returnValue = someFunction(x, y)
returnValue = x * y + 3
end
```

However, Matlab noted that I was not allowed to simply declare a function in the middle of my script. I tried moving the function to the top of the file, but Matlab forced me to rename my function to the name of the file.

I soon realized that Matlab functions must match the name of their files. How do I modularize my Matlab code within a single file? Is there a way I could just define a function in the middle of my script?

Comment: What's wrong with using multiple files?

Comment: @poorsod: For very small one line operations like these I think it would be more readable to have them in a single file; sort of like using the `inline` keyword for C++ functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Anonymous functions**

For very small functions like the one in your example, you could simply define an anonymous function like this: `f = @(x, y) x * y + 3`. You can define such functions even in the prompt of your workspace or in any script file.

**Nested functions**

If you turn your MATLAB script into a function, it will allow you to define nested functions:

```
function a = my_script(x)
  y = 3; 
  function r = some_function(b)
    r = b * y + 3;
  end
  a = some_function(x)
end
```

Note that the nested function can see the value of `y`. This can be handy for example, when you optimize parameters of an ODE and the solver you use doesn't provide a means to modify parameter values.

**Sub functions**

You can also define a function with multiple local sub functions in one single file. Sub functions are defined below the "public" function. In your example `some_function` could be a sub function in `my_script.m`.

```
function a = my_script(x)
  y = 3;
  p = 42;
  a = some_function(x, y) + p;
end

function r = some_function(x, y)
  r = x * y + 3;
end
```

The `end` keywords are optional here. In contrast to nested functions, sub functions are rather helpful to encapsulate pieces of an algorithm, as `some_function` will not see the value of `p`.

Comment: you can still have `end` keywords when using sub-functions.. Here is a doc page with an overview of of types of functions in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html

Answer (score 4):

An M file must be one of:

1. A script
2. A function
3. A class

If you do not start an M file with either a function or class declaration, then it is a script.  In that case, no functions can follow, unless then are anonymous functions, which can be defined anywhere.

If the first line of the file starts with a function, then that is the function that is executed when the file is run in MATLAB.  Multiple sub-functions can be defined in any order below the main function.  On a side note, the functions can optionally be terminated with an end, but then must all be consistently defined either with or without the end.

[Loren discusses the types of M files](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/08/26/what-kind-of-matlab-file-is-this/) and some ways of programmatically identifying the type of an M file.

The M-LINT code checker will tell you to rename the function or the file name to match, but this has historically not been enforced.

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah, my first answer. :D

Comment: Oh, really? Hey, I'm impressed. I don't even remember my first answer :-)

Comment: I've had to look in my profile to see which my first answer was. I'm not particularly proud of it :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is not way to declare multiple canonical functions in Matlab in a single file. However, using anonymous functions and functional programming techniques you may achieve some of your desired effect.

I recommend the series on functional program from Loren on the Art of Matlab - I use these techniques on a regular basis.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/07/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-3/