# Defining Functions in Sections of a MATLAB file

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to define functions inside of sections of a MATLAB file that you can call from the command window? I have three functions I want to define in a single `.m` file (each in its own section) but I don't see how I will be able to call them.

Comment: See also [How can I break up my Matlab code into functions without creating many files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18796978/2778484).

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Create folder myFuncitions and append plus sign in front of folder name like "+myFunctions" and move all your functions .m file in that folder. You can access functions: myFunction.Func1(), muFunctions.Func2(), and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Using class is your best bet. In class, you can define multiple methods (i.e. function) and call them independently of their order.

For example:

```
classdef Cat < handle
    properties
        meowCount = 0; 
    end

    methods 

        function obj = Cat()
            % all initializations, calls to base class, etc. here,
        end

        function Meow1(obj)
            disp('meowww'); 
            obj.meowCount = obj.meowCount + 1;
        end

        function Meow2(obj)
            disp('meowww meowww'); 
            obj.meowCount = obj.meowCount + 2;
        end
    end    
end
```

Demonstration:

```
>> C = Cat;
>> C.Meow1; 
meowww
>> C.meowCount
1
>> C.Meow2
meowww meowww
>> C.meowCount
3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to define more than one function per file in MATLAB, and access them from outside that file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab/3570017#3570017) gives a good answer. Sample code to implement it is

```
function fHandle=temp(fnum)

switch fnum
  case 1, fHandle=@func1;
  case 2, fHandle=@func2;
  case 3, fHandle=@func3;
end
end

function y=func1(x)
y=x+1;
end

function y=func2(x)
y=x+2;
end

function y=func3(x)
y=x+3;
end
```

From the command line type

> > f1=temp(1);f2=temp(2);f3=temp(3);

then
    [f1(1) f2(1) f3(1)]

gives

ans =
     2     3     4