# Multiple functions in Matlab file

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab file with multiple functions defined.  When calling the file, I get the following error: "Error: File: kmeans.m Line: 20 Column: 1\n Function definition is misplaced or improperly nested."

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3569946/1214731) for some good info on the topic.

Comment: Or see my [Cliff's Notes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18798433/2778484) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure every function has a matching `end`.

Comment: That's actually not necessary. Just be consistent. If one function has an end, they all need it, and the other way around.

Comment: @chappjc Sure, but I always suggest this as a "good practice" because they're needed for nested functions. So, if you always put an `end` you're most likely to not having this problem. :)