# How to use a Matlab script defined function in the Command Window

Tags: matlab

After I run a script, the variables and functions that I defined in the script are now available in the Command Window.

Is it possible to 'load' the function definitions in a script so that they execute in the Command Window?

As a workaround, if I insert a line with 'keyboard', this stops execution, displays the 'K>>' prompt, and now I can run functions and access variables.

Comment: You mean you have a bunch of anonymous function definitions in a script? Or you're trying to define more than one function in a file, this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796978/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/

Comment: You cannot call local or nested functions defined in a file from outside if that is what you are asking. You can only call the top function. You can return a bunch of function handles to each of the local functions which can be called from outside.